# Fully automate Windows Install from Boot drive

Tags: installation, automation, unattended, answerfile

I have a few things that I have not been able to automate with the Windows Setup. I have made an Unattend.xml file which does most of the heavy lifting. However, there are somethings that I am struggling to automate, namely during the very first parts of the install

1. <s>I want to automatically select the version to install (10 Enterprise)</s> Achieved this with the EI.cfg file, which I ignored up until now because the Microsoft page that I read said that the file was just ignored if there was an Unattend.xml file
2. I want to skip the Language Select screen (The very first screen you get when you boot into the install media. Im never going to change it, and it just makes another click that I have to do
3. Possible way to skip clicking Install Now? Is there a way to go straight into the installation process without needing to click the Install Now button?
4. Automatically accept license terms and hit Next?
5. Automatically select Custom Install
6. Delete all partitions, and without adding any new partitions, just hit next. (Drive 0 Unallocated Space)

Ive tried a few ways to do this through an answer file, however they never work properly. I managed to remove all partitions, however when it tried to install windows after that, it just rebooted

Comment: [AcceptEula](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-setup-userdata-accepteula). Creating partitions and language selection is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1025239/windows-10-unattended-install-how-to-set-input-locale-system-language-and-curr).  Suspect all your issues can be resolved with just the Unattend.xml file

Comment: @Ramhound None of the steps put forward in the links you sent were able to solve any of the "issues" that I am having. After making those changes and rebooting into the drive, I still had to go through all the same steps that I had to before. I do think that the partition steps worked, however I will have to wait until I reimage a brand new system to fully check if that worked

Comment: If **AcceptEula** didn’t work then your XML is at fault.

Comment: @Ramhound Im just headed into work right now, where my XML is. So ill post it in the thread. I guess I should have done that from the start, huh?